# Conditional Click Method not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

Following this [tutorial](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) I have an Ajax call that adds a row to a list, it works correctly adding in a new partial view to the list of existing items.

```
@model List<FTD.Models.Rate>

@using (Html.BeginForm("EditRates","Maintenance"))
{          
<div id="editorRows">
@foreach (FTD.Models.Rate _rate in Model)
{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Rate",_rate); 
}
</div>
@Html.ActionLink("Add Another", "BlankEditorRow", null, new { id = "addItem" })
<br />
<input id="Edit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Edit" />

 }
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $("#addItem").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
    });
    return false;
 </script>
```

I want to limit the list to 5 rows. I attempted to wrap an if around the $.ajax call however this results in displaying only that rather than adding a new partial to the current page I am redirected to BlankEditorRow.

```
$("#addItem").click(function () {
    if ($('.editorRow').length < 5) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.href,
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) { $("#editorRows").append(html); }
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult BlankEditorRow()
 {
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        return PartialView("_Rate", new Rate());
    return View("_Rate", new Rate());
 }
```

_Rate Partial

```
@model FTD.Models.Rate

<div class="editorRow">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.Date, new { @class = "date" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Date)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.InterestRate)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.InterestRate)
    <a href="#" class="deleteRow">delete</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want `$('.editorRow').length < 5` - i.e. `.length` the attribute and not `.length()`;

Comment: You are correct in that, however it doesn't change the issue I am encountering. When I use the if statement I get bounced to BlankEditorRow without it the partial renders into the list of rows.

Answer (score 1):

You should be seeing an error in the JavaScript console on this line:

```
if ($('.editorRow').length() < 5) {
```

[`length`](http://api.jquery.com/length/) is a property, not a function. So:

```
if ($('.editorRow').length < 5) {
```

---

For debugging things like this, nothing beats [using a debugger](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html), and having the console open, making sure the browser is set to tell you about errors, etc., etc. The tools are there to be used.

Comment: I am using fiddler and firebug thanks. What I am asking is why adding code before the ajax call results in a completely different action?

Comment: @Cookie: You'll need to clarify the question, it's not clear at all what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to clarify. The first jquery first and the result is a row row added to the list. Putting any statement prior to the $.ajax has the effect of rendering a new page with only one row.